# Automatic mail directories implied by address, preferably on a CentOS Cpanel setup

Tags: email, smtp, imap, dovecot

To put it simple, i have a default email me@abiusx.com,
i want every other email like x@abiusx.com to be forwarded to that default email, but in a way that i know its been sent to x@abiusx.com (put in a folder, has some headers, etc.)

Using dovecot as IMAP server, exim as SMTP on a CentOS 5.5 CPanel VPS and client is Mail.app

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it concerns the use of shared web hosting by end users or resellers, rather than the administration of web hosting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cPanel you can do this by setting up a catch-all address and then adding the headers with a cpanel user filter as described here:

http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/UserFiltering